# In Google Container Builder, is the `dir:` mapped?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have two containers, the first modifies some files in the repo and the second has those files `ADD`ed into it, locally I would map a volume on my host machine and they could both use it, is this possible in Container Builder? I am not seeing the changes the first container made in my second container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only directory that persists across build steps is the `/workspace` directory; see the documentation for further details: https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/build-steps.

Comment: I'm using a subdirectory of /workspace. I'm guessing the persistence is recursive? If so it must be a problem with my code.

Comment: Yes indeed, the persistence is recursive. It's `/workspace` and everything under it that persists. Note that we don't do anything to stop you from putting a symlink in `/workspace` that links to a file outside of `/workspace`, and the target of that symlink would not persist across build steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  args: ['cp', '-r', 'gs://${_BUCKET_PREFIX}/model', '/workspace']
  id: 'download-model'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['run',
         '--name', 'abc-model',
         '--volume', '/workspace/model:/tmp',
         '--env', 'input_model_path=/tmp',
         '--env', 'output_model_path=/tmp/processed',
         'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/model-processor:latest']
  id: 'run-model-processor'
```

The above code works for me most of the time but it has been flaky sometimes when the `/workspace/model` is not mounted correctly (cannot detect content under the directory when the image runs). But since it's a sub-dir of `/workspace` I assume it's persisted.